# How can I take a specific number of lines of input in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am taking inputs in Ruby like this:

```
lines = STDIN.readlines.map{|x| x.strip.to_i}.sort
```

This takes input from the command prompt, but I want to take input a specific number of times.  Suppose my number of test cases is 3, how can I stop it after 3 lines of input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
lines = []
3.times do
  lines << STDIN.readline.strip.to_i
end
lines.sort
```

---

### EDIT:

If you are saying that you want it to accept an *arbitrary* number of inputs, you have a couple options:  The simplest is to first input how many lines of input you have, like this:

```
num_lines = STDIN.readline.strip.to_i
lines = []
num_lines.times do
  lines << STDIN.readline.strip.to_i
end
lines.sort
```

Or, if you don't know how many lines to expect, you have to have some way of signifying that the data is complete.  For example, if you want to have an empty line mean the end of the data:

```
lines = []
STDIN.each_line do |line|
  line.strip!
  break if line == ''
  lines << line.to_i
end
lines.sort
```

By the way, when the program is paused while awaiting input, this is not called an "infinite loop".  It is "blocking" or simply "waiting for input".

Comment: it still goes in infinite loop .. i am sorry

Comment: No it doesn't, I've just tested it.  Perhaps you're using the phrase "infinite loop" incorrectly?

Comment: Maybe he means this will wait indefintely if the user only puts in two or less lines of input (not from a pipe)?

Comment: @rampion: That would not be an infinite loop would it?

Comment: I just slammed my face into my desk. I am feeling incredibly dizzy and I am sure I lost a few brain cells. I am afraid I still cannot agree with your definition of an infinite loop.

Comment: Why not gets instead of STDIN?

Comment: @Radar: First, it reflects the same structure as in the question.  Second, I find STDIN.readline more readily apparent to a newbie than gets.  But there's no real reason not to use gets instead.

Answer (score 2):

One line of code...

This will take only the number of lines you want to use - the desired count is in variable @requested_count:

```
lines = STDIN.readlines.values_at(0..@requested_count - 1).map{|x| x.strip.to_i}.sort
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `gets`?

```
lines = []
1.upto(3) do
  lines << gets.to_i
end

puts lines.sort
```

Comment: Cargo cult programming: I was thinking about the "get a specific number of lines" part of the problem and simply copied that part of the code from previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the previous answers:

```
lines = []
1.upto(3) do
  lines << STDIN.readline.strip.to_i
end
puts lines.sort
```